# AWS codepipeline doesn't update code on the domain url when pushed to github

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I am fairly new to AWS and using AWS(codepipeline + Elastic Beanstalk) and I connected my github account.

My files have the following piece if code if needed:-

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "dev": "node ./src/index.ts",
    "start":"node build/index.js"
  },
```

buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: latest
    commands:
      - npm install -g typescript
      - npm install -g mocha
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Installing source NPM dependencies...
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - npm run build
      - npm prune --production
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
  files:
    - build/**/*
    - package.json
    - package-lock.json
    - node_modules/**/*
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

In pipelines for source and deploy i dont get any warnings or errors [image: as you can see here]

but then when i open beanstalk domain url which serves the project, I dont see the reflected changes (even though i see them on github repo).

****If i build in my local machine and then upload that build folder to beanstalk the changes are reflected then****

What could be possibly wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you are missing **Code Build** stage in your **Code Pipeline**, which will basically execute this `buildspec.yml` file.

**Build** stage will appear right after **Source**, and before the **Deploy** stage, as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

To do this, you need to add a **Build Action Provider** in your **Code Pipeline** as highlighted in the below picture.

[image]

Comment: even after adding build stage, the build was success but still no changes were updated on the url

Comment: is there something wrong in my buildspec.yml although my build command also seems to be executed in logs of codebuild

Comment: Can you please check the input artifact for the deploy stage should be the output of build stage, not the output of source stage.